# Find different values in one column according to same value in second column

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
colA     colB
---------------
!690     519745
!690     519748
!690     519748
!690     519748
!690     519748
!688     519752
!688     519752
!688     519752
!688     519760
!688     519760
!700     519760
```

And I am looking for sql query which can find me records where for same value in colB aren't same values in colA. Like last records in colB 519760.

Many thanks for help.

Comment: GROUP BY, having count = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
select colb
from table t
group by colb
having min(cola) <> max(cola);
```

This returns all the values in `colb` that have more than one value in `cola`.  You could also use:

```
having count(distinct cola) > 1
```

This works, but `count(distinct)` is less efficient than `min()` and `max()`.